# OnChange event does not work properly

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

My OnChange event does not work properly - I want to trigger a function **when** user changes a textbox's value. But in my tests I have seen that the function triggers when textbox's value changes **and** textbox loses focus. Something wrong with my browser? Or is it about the ability of JavaScript? If the last one is true how can I can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your code here in description....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onchange` event will trigger when an input field loses focus or when an option is selected from a dropdown menu, that's normal behavior.

If you want an event that will be triggered as the user types in an input field, you can use [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), [onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) or [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) events.

Comment: True, worth adding `onpaste` as well when user put value via the mouse only. Plus, `onkeydown` happens **before** any value change, ideal event would be `onkeyup` that happens after the key was released and the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with jquery:

```
$("textbox_id").keyup(function(){
   //do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write the jquery code on keyup event and blur event also, because if user paste some copied data into textbox by using mouse only in that case only blur event called by jquery.